# Using group presentation, does $\langle A = a^3, 1 = A^2 \rangle$ relate to $\langle A = a^2, 1 = A^3\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, discrete-optimization, monoid

Let $G = \langle A = a^3, 1 = A^2 \rangle$ relate to $H  = \langle A = a^2, 1 = A^3\rangle$ be two "group presentations" namely for:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\cdot & A & a & a^2 & 1 & Aa & Aa^2 \\
A & 1 & Aa & Aa^2 & A & a & a^2\\
a & \dots \\
a^2 \\
1 \\
A a \\
\vdots
\end{matrix}
$$

In other words the structure they induce is indeed finite.  Though I'm not sure if it's a group.  That's okay, I'll work with whatever structure it naturally is in general.

They come from these two smallest grammars:

$$
G = \{S \to AA, A \to aaa \}, \\
H = \{S \to AAA, A \to aa \},
$$

namely by direct translation and identifying $\rightarrow$ with $=$ and $S$ with $1$.

Can we tell if the structures are isomorphic or not?  If not, it simply means you have a finite set of isomorphism classes of straight-line grammar associated structures.

Another question: how do they relate to inefficient grammars for the same string $s = a^6$, such as $I = \{ S \to aaAa, A \to aaa \}$ and their respective groups?

---

Note that in the group constructed, $x = y$ iff they expand to the same string, thus you may or may not have $\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$  in general, but you do when $\Sigma = \{a\}$ is singleton, because everything commutes in that case.

Comment: This group is either of order 6 or reduces down to a smaller order, and all finite groups (especially of small order) are well-studied and understood. There are only two groups of order 6, why not take a look and see if this is one of them? You might have to do a little bit of work to see if the representations are the same. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_6

Comment: Both groups are cyclic of order 6, with generator $a$.

Comment: I get the feeling this is the cyclic group of order 6. I’m thinking about it as the additive group, but if you rename $1$ to $0$, $A=3$, and $a=1$ I think you’ll find this all checks out.

Comment: @JackCrawford then the two groups are isomorphic? If so that would be cool.

Comment: *reposting this comment because I made an error. Yes, they are isomorphic. The elements in the normal cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_6$, “$0,1,2,3,4,5$” (again, I like to think additively) get mapped under isomorphism to $G$ as “$1, a, a^2, A, Aa, Aa^2$” and to $H$ as “$1, a, A, Aa, A^2, A^2a$”. They are all isomorphic. We see that $a$ is treated like the same element in both groups (the generating element) but in $G$, you treat $A$ like it is $3$ and in $H$ you treat $A$ like it is $2$.

Comment: @JackCrawford see my slight generalization below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_6$, and generated by $a$.

An isomorphism between them is fully determined just by sending $a$ to $a$ (to the generating element in $\mathbb{Z}_6$). Note that this will send $A$ in $G$ to $Aa$ in $H$ and likewise send $A$ in $H$ to $a^2$ in $G$.

The reason why all of this works is because the cyclic groups of orders 2 and 3 are subgroups of the cyclic group of order 6, and $G$ and $H$ have just been phrased to emphasise this fact. If you’re looking at any finite group, you will be able to make as many presentations like these as there are cyclic subgroups of your finite group.

Comment: I think for $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$ you only introduce a variable $A = \gamma$ if it can be found in some grammar $g \implies s$ and you keep powering $a$: $a, a^2, a^3, \cdots$ until the group fills out the table.  In other words the problem with more letters is what do you do when you concatenate and the result isn't a substring?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not quite sure I understand how grammars connect to group theory -- I can understand strings as monoids, sure, but I don't understand how the invertibility part comes into it. When you say "concatenate, and the result isn't a substring" do you mean constructing some string out of $a$ and $b$ that aren't in the Cayley table for the group? because of course you can still arbitrarily express any string of $a$ and $b$ in your group no matter the length (even if your group is finite), the Cayley table only gives you one minimal coset of the group.

Comment: It turns out that for $|\Sigma| \gt 1$ you get a one-relator group $\langle \Sigma \vert 1 = s \rangle$ which is a quotient of the free group on $a, b$.  So the idea is to define and then create an algorithm to search for, a minimal presentation of a certain form.  Since the one relator group will have many alternative presentations which will almost always include extending the alphabet $\Sigma$.  You take your grammar $g = \{ S \to AA, A \to aaa\}$ and form the relations $A^{-1} a^3 = 1 = A^2$ with $\Sigma = \{A, a\}$.  Should be same group, right?

Comment: There are many results on one-relator groups such as the "word problem for one-relator groups" is solvable.  It's unclear what results are related to this problem though, if any.  The idea is that if you can associate a group presentation with the grammar then at least you're now in a group setting, the undesirable alternative being pure grammars with weird operations on them that aren't very "algebraic".

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above, the two groups are isomorphic.  So I conjecture:

> *If $g, h$ are two straight-line grammars of a string $s$ over $\Sigma = \{a\}$ then their associated groups $G, H$ are such that $G \simeq H$.  In particular, the group associated with any string $s = a^n, n \gt 0$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.*

The smallest grammar problem is then to compute the smallest presentation of the form:

$$
\langle \text{non-generator} = \text{string of non-generator and generator} \rangle
$$

where the cost of the presentation is the sum of the lengths of the right hand sides.  I know this format definition needs some work such as it can't include occurrences of $\cdot ^{-1}$, the inverse operator.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the language of straight-line grammars and their associated groups — where could I find some introductory readings on this? Thanks! (I want to have a deeper think about your conjecture)

Comment: @JackCrawford google "the smallest grammar problem" and you'll turn up essentially all the research out there that exists, and there isn't a lot.  It's one of those computational problems (finding some smallest grammar of an input string), such that if you prove it polynomial in time means $P = NP$.  I've written several algorithms that try to compute it and they all start to slow down at around $n = 100, $ ie $a^n = s$ indicating that $P \neq NP$, but how do you prove it, you know? We need to associate the grammars with groups.  Would you like to collaborate with me on this problem?

Comment: @JackCrawford *straight-line* just means the CFG generates only a single string language.  So you could also call them *single-string CFG's*.  Thus it's like the ultimate Huffman-like compression of a string but incredibly difficult to compute, maybe.